# Finding the max value from a column and populating another column based on the max value

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have incremental load in csv files. I read the csv in a dataframe. The dataframe has one column containing some strings. I have to find the distinct strings from this column and assign an `ID` (integer) to each of the value starting from `0` after joining one other dataframe.

In the next run, I have to assign the ID after finding out the max value in `ID` column and incrementing it for different strings. Wherever there is a null in `ID` column, I have to increment it (+1) from the value of the previous run.

**FIRST RUN**

| string | ID |
| --- | --- |
| zero | 0 |
| first | 1 |
| second | 2 |
| third | 3 |
| fourth | 4 |

**SECOND RUN**

`MAX(ID) = 4`

| string | ID |
| --- | --- |
| zero | 0 |
| first | 1 |
| second | 2 |
| third | 3 |
| fourth | 4 |
| fifth | 5 |
| sixth | 6 |
| seventh | 7 |
| eighth | 8 |

I have tried this but couldn't make it working..

```
max = df.agg({"ID": "max"}).collect()[0][0]
df_incremented = df.withcolumn("ID", when(col("ID").isNull(),expr("max += 1")))
```

Let me know if there is an easy way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you keep only distinct values, you can use `row_number` function over window :

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

 df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("a",), ("a",), ("b",), ("c",), ("d",), ("e",), ("e",)],
    ("string",)
)

w = Window.orderBy("string")

df1 = df.distinct().withColumn("ID", F.row_number().over(w) - 1)

df1.show()
#+------+---+
#|string| ID|
#+------+---+
#|     a|  0|
#|     b|  1|
#|     c|  2|
#|     d|  3|
#|     e|  4|
#+------+---+
```

Now let's add some rows into this dataframe and use `row_number` along with `coalesce` to assign `ID` only for row where it's null (no need to get the max):

```
df2 = df1.union(spark.sql("select * from values ('f', null), ('h', null), ('i', null)"))

df3 = df2.withColumn("ID", F.coalesce("ID", F.row_number(w) - 1))

df3.show()
#+------+---+
#|string| ID|
#+------+---+
#|     a|  0|
#|     b|  1|
#|     c|  2|
#|     d|  3|
#|     e|  4|
#|     f|  5|
#|     h|  6|
#|     i|  7|
#+------+---+
```

If you wanted to keep duplicated values too and assign them the same `ID`, then use `dense_rank` instead of `row_number`.

Comment: thanks @blackbishop. Your logic looks better i guess. But mine also worked for me now. I tried this again with some modifications..





df.withColumn(id_col_name, F.when(F.col("ID").isNull(),
            F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())))
            .otherwise(df["ID"]))

Comment: Hi @hotshot_02, yes, `coalesce` is the same as  `case/when` expression in this case, I prefered it because it's shorter ;) Glad it helped you to solve the question!